# Splitting columns of a numpy array easily

Tags: python, numpy

How can I split an array's columns into three arrays x, y, z without manually writing each of the `[:,0],[:,1],[:,2]` separately?

### Example

```
# Create example np array
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

Now `data` is

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

What I want to do:

```
x, y, z = data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2] ## Help me here!
print(x)
```

Wanted output:

```
array([1, 4, 7])
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Transpose, then unpack:

```
>>> x, y, z = data.T
>>> x
array([1, 4, 7])
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to slice it.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> x, y, z = data.T
>>> x
array([1, 4, 7])
>>> y
array([2, 5, 8])
>>> z
array([3, 6, 9])
```